# DAX: Dynamically update calculated column values with slicer

Tags: math, powerbi, data-visualization, dax, slicers

I've got the problem with setting up slicer and modifying calculated column

What am I trying to achieve -

Modify the line chart with slicer's value.

How values for the chart are calculated currently -

`Result =if(B = "Name", (Val1-Val2)/(Conval 1 * (conval2 – conval3 * X)) / 10, 1)`

Where:

1. Val 1 and Val 2 – calculated columns
2. Conval 1: 3 – Measures with 1
3. value X - to be variable, currently it is constant value

Example in excel (marked the variable with yellow)

[image: Example from Excel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible for a slicer to modify a calculated column because calculated columns are only computed once each time you load your data rather than every time you interact with filters and slicers.

If you want calculations that respond to slicers, then you must use a measure. It might look something like this:

```
Result =
IF (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Table1[Type] ) = "Name",
    DIVIDE (
        SUMX ( Table1, Table1[Val1] - Table2[Val2] ),
        [ConVal1] * ( [ConVal2] - [ConVal3] * [X] ) * 10
    ),
    1
)
```

Comment: Hello Alexis, thank you for the hint, i have solved the issue with following algorithm - 

1. I have calculated the difference between Val1 and Val2 as separate column in table;
2. Used 'Values()' to convert it into measurement
3. Corrected original formula to use: Calculate (Divide (), type in {value}*) and created new measure
4. It worked. This was done for each type, and all measures were added to chart separately.
 
Although it has some limitations towards visualization, by the end of the day it works. Hopefully it might help someone  

* used for filtering through types